# Serializing and de-serializing structs for passing over UDP sockets

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to serialize the following struct into a string and then use the UDP sendto method to send it over the network stream. Subsequently at the receiving end I want to deserialize the string and recompose the struct.

This is the struct definition.

```
typedef struct PATH{
    int server1;
    int server2;
    int weight;
}PATH;
```

This is the serialize method

```
char* serialize(PATH** arr, int sz){

    char* buffer = (50, sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < sz ; ++i)
    {
        &buffer+= arr[i]->server1:
        &buffer+= arr[i]->server2;
        &buffer+= arr[i]->weight;

    }
    buffer+='\n';

    return buffer;

}
```

The error I end up getting is

```
src/message.c:5:11: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'unsigned long' [-Wint-conversion]
    char* buffer = (50, sizeof(int));
          ^        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/message.c:9:13: error: expression is not assignable
        &buffer+= arr[i]->server1:
        ~~~~~~~^
src/message.c:11:13: error: expression is not assignable
        &buffer+= arr[i]->weight;
        ~~~~~~~^
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Addition isn't bitwise copying; you should be using `memcpy` instead. Also note that you will need to account for endianness and padding differences between the machines.

Comment: Why the double *? You are serializing an array of struct. Where the '50' comes from? at least make it '60' (or 30). Buffer is already a pointer, don't need a &, but above all, look at what @Colonel Thirty Two said.

Comment: Have you looked at the XDR library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the correct syntax to allocate memory dynamically; it looks like you may have intended to call `calloc`, but left out the function.

You can't use `+=` to assign to an address and increment the variable, you need to use indirection. You also need to save the original `buffer` address, and increment a different variable, so you can return the start of the buffer at the end. And the pointer that you use during the iteration needs to be `int*`, so that it will step through the buffer by the size of `int`, not single characters.

```
char* serialize(PATH** arr, int sz){

    char* buffer = calloc(50, sizeof(int));
    int *p = (int*)buffer;

    for (int i = 0; i < sz ; ++i)
    {
        *(p++) = arr[i]->server1:
        *(p++) = arr[i]->server2;
        *(p++) = arr[i]->weight;

    }
    *(p++) = '\n';

    return buffer;
}
```

Note that this is just sending the binary representation of the integers, it's not converting them to strings. It seems strange that you would use a newline delimiter in a binary protocol -- it would probably be better to send `sz` first, then the receiver can simply use a `for` loop to read that many repetitions.

To deal with endian issues, you probably should call `htonl()` when sending the data, and `ntohl()` when receiving. E.g. serialize should do:

```
$(p++) = htonl(arr[i]->server1);
```

and so on.

Comment: So to cater for the endieness can I use something like htons(arr[i]->server1)

Comment: But since it's a string that I'm passing, would the byte order matter. Can't I just use inet_aton() to pass and inet_nota() to receive.

Comment: I've added an example

Comment: You're not passing a string. `arr[i]->server1` is an `int`.

Comment: What I meant was the buffer that is returned from the function. That is a string.

Comment: `buffer` is an array of `int`, not a string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95732/discussion-between-antithesis-and-barmar).